# How to concat columns in bookshelf.js?

Tags: sql, node.js, postgresql, knex.js, bookshelf.js

Trying to select columns with bookshelf and concat ids. My db is postgresql. In knex, I do it like this:

```
knex('client_users')
    .select(
        'client_user_id as id',
        'status',
        'email',
        'last_login_date as lastLoginDate',
        knex.raw(`CONCAT(first_name, ' ', last_name) as "displayName"`)
    )
    .whereIn('client_user_id', clientUserIds)
    .andWhere('status', 'pending')
    .tap(clientUsers => console.log('clientUsers retrieved:', clientUsers));
```

It does the job and returns:

```
[{
    id: 1, 
    status: 'pending', 
    email: 'pennywise@derry.com, 
    lastLoginDate: [Date Object], 
    displayName: 'John Smith'}, 
    {...}, {...}, etc]
```

The docs aren't clear and I see in the docs they have select, but nothing about what params it needs or how to do what I want :(

Answer (score 3):

Alright, the solution was pretty stupid, in my opinion. So I have my model named `ClientUsers` and all I had to do was add `.query()` the docs really aren't clear about this. Oh well... Not really what I expected to be honest, maybe there is a better way.

```
ClientUsers.query()
    .select(
        'client_user_id as id',
        'status',
        'email',
        'last_login_date as lastLoginDate',
        knex.raw('CONCAT(first_name, \' \', last_name) as "displayName"')
    )
    .whereIn('client_user_id', clientUserIds)
    .andWhere('status', 'pending')
    .tap(clientUsers => console.log('clientUsers retrieved:', clientUsers));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
let url = "http://google.com/";

let result = await db.select(
"id", "title", 
db.raw(`CONCAT('${url}',icon) as "icon"`)).from('event_types').where('status', '=', true);
```

keep in mind single and tilde sign